# How to change the Array Element names in XmlSerialization?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Consider the following code:

```
[Serializable]
public class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then,

```
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {   
            Human[] mans = new Human[] { 
                new Human() { Name = "Moim" }
                    };

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Human[]));
            xs.Serialize(ms, mans);
            string s = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
```

At this point, the variable s will hold a value like,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfHuman xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Human>
    <Name>Moim</Name>
  </Human>
</ArrayOfHuman>
```

Now all I need to do is, changing the xml array root element 'ArrayOfHuman' to something like 'MyFavoriteArrayRootName'. I have seen the IXmlSerializable interface but, that skips the root element name. Anybody has got any idea how to achieve this?

All comments will be greatly appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Human[]), XmlRootAttribute("MyFavoriteArrayRootName"));
```

Answer (score 2):

**new** keyword was missing before XmlRootAttribute.

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(Human[]), new XmlRootAttribute("MyFavoriteArrayRootName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the XmlRoot on your Human class like this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("MyFavoriteArrayRootName")]
public class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```